# Can this probability be computed by the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $50$ balls numerated on a box. Let the event be "to draw five balls such that the order doesn't matter and there's no replacement".
>   Let $\alpha \in\{1,2,...,50\}$. The probability of $\alpha$ being drawn is given by 
>   $\frac{^{49}C_{4}}{^{50}C_{5}}$.

But if the event is repeated $n$ times, how can I compute the probability of the $\alpha$ number to be drawn again, $p$ times $\left( p \leq n \right)$?

I thought about the binomial distribution where the probability of success is $\frac{^{49}C_{4}}{^{50}C_{5}} \approx 0,1$.

Comment: What is meant with "again" ? Does the first try count as an extra try ?

Comment: Probably, you simply mean $p$ sucesses in $n$ tries. Then, you can use the binomial distribution because the events are independent, and the probability of sucess is always the same.

Comment: The approx sign is not neccessary.

Comment: @Peter the meaning is to have $p$ sucesses in $n$ tries. Thanks